# Arduino LoRa Send and Receive Data

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lora, lorawan

I tried to send and receive data using 2 Arduino Unos, 2 LoRa chips (SX1278 433MHz), 2 antennas and 2 Arduino IDE instances.

The problem is with the receiving data command.

This is the code for SENDING command:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

int counter = 0;

const int ss = 10;          
const int reset = 9;     
const int dio0 = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  LoRa.begin(433E6);
  LoRa.setPins(ss, reset, dio0);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);

  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();

  counter++;

  delay(5000);
}
```

On serial monitor, I succeed in sending packages, but not receiving. This is the RECEIVING code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

const int ss = 10;        
const int reset = 9;       
const int dio0 = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  LoRa.begin(433E6);
  LoRa.setPins(ss, reset, dio0);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

}

void loop() {
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet '");

    // read packet
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
      Serial.print("hello ");
    }

    // print RSSI of packet
    Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
    Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  }
}
```

I used instructions about connections from this git page:
https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa

Answer (score 1):

To make [this board](https://www.banggood.com/Wemos-SX1278-LoRa-ESP32-Bluetooth-WIFI-Lora-Internet-Antenna-Development-Board-For-Arduino-TTGO-p-1214812.html) work, I had to explicitly initialize SPI

```
SPI.begin(/*sck*/ 5, /*miso*/ 19, /*mosi*/ 27, /*ss*/ cs);
```

It may be the same for yours. Also, you should properly initialize Lora:

```
while (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
}
Serial.println("LoRa Initializing OK!");
```

With the code you posted, you don't really know if it initialized correcly or if it's actually sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

First I haven't worked with tbe Lora library. I worked with the SX1278 library. So I can help you with that.
First here is the link to the library - [Lora SX1278.h library](https://github.com/dinurymomshad/Lora-Traffic-Control)

Now you might ask why I'm not using the library from the original GitHub repo. Well  I faced qn issue with that library and the issue is this:

> The sx1278::getPacket() library function is modified to stabilize the Lora receive functionality. There was a bug which led the esp to panic. The payloadlength read from the REG_FIFO register was not checked for valid value which led to reading the REG_FIFO register read for over 65000 times. Moreover yield() is added in time consuming parts of this function.

That is why I'm using this custom library. Anyway, for you:
You can use this function to send packet:

```
T_packet_state = sx1278.sendPacketTimeoutACK(ControllerAddress, message); //T_packet_state is 0 if the packet data is sent successful.
```

Also to receive data use this function:

```
R_packet_state = sx1278.receivePacketTimeoutACK(); //R_packet_state is 0 if the packet data is received successfully.
```

And at the beginning of the code just define a few things:

```
//Lora SX1278:
#define LORA_MODE 10 //Add your suitable mode from the library
#define LORA_CHANNEL CH_6_BW_125 //Ch number and Bandwidth
#define LORA_ADDRESS 3 //Address of the device from which you will send data
uint8_t ControllerAddress = 5; //Address of receiving end device
```

My first decent answer on StackOverflow. Fingers crossed.